# Can you help solving a problem about first-child and after selectors?

Tags: html, css-selectors

I need to display the word `first` after the first child of each section:

```
section:first-child::after {
     content: "first";
}
```

Comment: That CSS will insert a text node at the bottom of each section that says "first".

Comment: But how could i insert the word "first"  after the first-child of each section type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you didn't set the parent of the element. All elements in CSS are inherited from `body`.
In your example, `section` is handled as:

```
body section: first-child
```

If there is nothing before the `section` element and it is the first child of `body`, then it will have the specified properties.
Else properties will be ignored.

You should wrap the `section` into a container. For example:

```
<div id="parent">
  <section>...</section>
  <section>...</section>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.parent section:first-child::after {
  content: "first";
}
```